# Tracking a change of web directory in Google Analytics

Tags: directory, analytics

We recently changed the directory structure for our website.  For example the following page was listed changed as follows:

> Previous: /degrees/msm-technology/
>
> Current: /degrees/masters/ms-management/technology/

They are the same directory with the same pages just listed differently.

I'm attempting to do a custom filter Search and Replace to update the previous page so that there is not an interruption in data when tracking the pages.  However it doesn't seem to be working.

Filter Field Request URI -

> Search string ^/degrees/msm-technology/
>
> Replace string:  /degrees/masters/ms-management/technology/

The data for the previous page listed ends this week, while the other begins.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the hyphen like this

```
Search string: ^/degrees/msm\-technology/
```

because GA filters use POSIX Regex.

[source: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034836?hl=en]

Hope this helps.